# Blockchain.info js verifier error

Tags: blockchain.info

[image: superfish what?]

I got this error connecting to blockchain.info, does anyone know what that means?

Comment: I can't reproduce, and I'm also on chrome. Is it a specific page on blockchain.info? Do you have any toolbars installed?

Answer (score 2):

Basically, I think you have a Google Chrome extension (possibly FastSave 1.1) that is overlaying their ads with superfish's ad-serving network.

See here for reference:
http://www.fergeeks.com/chrome-tips/fast-save-1-1-chrome-extension-adding-ads-causing-havoc/

Check the chrome extensions you have; disable one by one. This is a particularly unobtrusive and semi-non-harmful (to you) virus that allows a malicious developer to replace ads you view with ads they serve.

Comment: Ok I've removed all the more "shady" extensions, and I'll see if that happens again...